# NodeList for loop in reverse order?

Tags: android, xml, for-loop, kotlin, nodelist

I'm trying to parse xml in reverse order, but can't get it to work. Here's the working code in the right order:

```
val nodeList = doc.getElementsByTagName("mytag")
for (i in 0 until nodeList.length) {
  // do something
}
```

The following code causes an exception:

```
val nodeList = doc.getElementsByTagName("mytag")
for (i in nodeList.length downTo 0) {
  // do something
}
```

The following code works but leaves out the last item:

```
val nodeList = doc.getElementsByTagName("mytag")
for (i in nodeList.length-1 downTo 0) {
   // do something
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you not do something like `nodeList.reversed().foreach{}` ?

Comment: It doesn't allow me to do that, reversed() causes "Unresolved reference. None of the following candidates is applicable because of receiver type mismatch"

Comment: `for (i in nodeList.length-1 downTo 0)` will iterate from last index of list to 0th index. Print the indexes and check on your own. So my guess is the code inside the for loop might be the culprit.

Comment: What type is `doc`, which xml library are you using parse it?

Comment: Seems to be working now. The xml contains live data, but for some reason it doesn't always show the same results as in the browser.

Comment: javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory